# ActiveRecord RecordNotFound Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I created a CRUD using the scaffold .

```
rails g scaffold intermediate_level/memory_game
```

And then I created the method Play, but when I call the method play an error is returned.
**http://localhost:3000/intermediate_level/memory_game/play?id=1**

```
Couldn't find IntermediateLevel::MemoryGame with 'id'=play
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_intermediate_level_memory_game
      @intermediate_level_memory_game = IntermediateLevel::MemoryGame.find(params[:id])
    end
```

---

```
def play {
       @intermediate_level_memory_game = IntermediateLevel::MemoryGame.find(params[:id])
    }
```

My routes.file

```
namespace :intermediate_level do
    resources :memory_game
    get 'memory_game/play' 
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom `get 'memory_game/play` should come before `resources :memory_game`.  Rails evaluates routes in the order in which they are listed in the routes.rb file, with the routes closest to the top of the file receiving the highest priority.

Answer (score 1):

With your given routes information:

```
  namespace :intermediate_level do
    resources :memory_game
    get 'memory_game/play'
  end
```

You have these two routes:

```
GET    /intermediate_level/memory_game/:id(.:format)      intermediate_level/memory_game#show
```

**and**

```
GET    /intermediate_level/memory_game/play(.:format)     intermediate_level/memory_game#play
```

When you make this request:

```
http://localhost:3000/intermediate_level/memory_game/play?id=1
```

it is matched by both of those routes and as you defined: `resources :memory_game` **before** `get 'memory_game/play'` in your `routes.rb` file, so the first one (`GET    /intermediate_level/memory_game/:id`) comes into action as that has higher priority, (**because Routes have priority defined by the order of appearance of the routes in the `config/routes.rb` file**) and then it tries to find the memory game with `id` param which in that case is `play` but fails to do so (as you don't have any memory game where `id=play`) and fails with the error message:

```
Couldn't find IntermediateLevel::MemoryGame with 'id'=play
```

One quick way to get around this issue is to reorder your routes like this:

```
  namespace :intermediate_level do
    get 'memory_game/play'
    resources :memory_game
  end
```

Then, your request url `http://localhost:3000/intermediate_level/memory_game/play?id=1` will be served by `GET    /intermediate_level/memory_game/play(.:format)     intermediate_level/memory_game#play` route which is what you want.

Comment: thanks, it was exactly that! Thanks for the great explanation as well.

Comment: @GleydsonS.Tavares welcome :) Glad it helped you fix your problem. You should consider accepting an answer. To see how accepting answers work, see this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work